# filtering based on multiple attributes in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of object having multiple attributes. I have a requirement to filter the array based on many attributes. lets say all the objects having firstname as "John" and who lives in "India" and "30" years of age.

I have done this by putting `&&` condition after each filtering, but I am planning to use Underscore.js in my project. Please let me know if Underscore.js can help me write in a more elegant manner?

Json Data:

```
  {
    "recordsTotal": 5,
    "recordsFiltered": 5,
    "aaData": [
    {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Kumar",
      "city": "Dhaka",
      "country": "Bangladesh",
      "age": "30"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "John",
       "lastname": "Wells",
       "city": "Katmandu",
       "country": "Nepal",
       "age": "28"
    },
    {
       "firstname": "Praveen",
       "lastname": "Garg",
       "city": "columbo",
       "country": "Srilanka",
       "age": "40"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Joe",
        "lastname": "Wells",
        "city": "Luton",
        "country": "UK",
        "age": "12"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Rita",
        "lastname": "Wahlin",
        "city": "houston",
        "country": "USA",
        "age": "28"
    }
  ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function _.filter which lets you pass every element of a collection to a function to test whether to include it in the returned filtered list.

So I think you would need something like:

```
var filtered = _filter(data.aaData, function(item) {
  return (item.firstname == 'John') && (item.country == 'India') && (age == '30'); 
})
```

See: http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the filter method of underscore, you can pass it in a list of objects, and arbitrarily specify the constraints for each field of the object:

```
var filtered = _.filter(data, function(item){
   return item.firstname == "John" && item.country == "India" && item.age == 30;
});
```

alternatively if you have a user defineable list of filters you could:

```
var filters = {
    "firstname":"John",
    "country":"India",
    "age":"30"
}
var filtered = _.filter(data, function(item){
   for(filter in filters){
       if(item[filter] != filters[filter]){ return false;}
   }
   return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

It is fast regular expression, no need to include extra js file except jQuery.

```
var result = $.grep(xx.aaData, function (e) { return e.firstname == 'john' && e.country == 'india' && e.age == '30'; });
```

where xx is your main json object